# Used package for thesis and reference style

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, packages

While I'm writing my thesis I realize that I have used many packages, and when I write some questions in `stackexchange` some of the answers came with deleting some packages, the following packages is what I used:

```
%Used packages%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% language package%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1256,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ arabic ,english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ptm}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%graphics packages%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Math packages%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\allowdisplaybreaks
%\usepackage{antpolt}
%\usepackage{cmbright}
%\usepackage{mathtime}
%\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage{ccfonts}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ptm}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\hbar}{\hslash}}    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%bibliography%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% what packages should I use for bibliography?
\usepackage[numbers,square,authoryear,sort&compress]{natbib} 
%\usepackage{bibtex}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}     
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%hyperlinks%
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{color, xcolor}    
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}    
\def\UrlBigBreaks{\do\/\do-\do:}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
citecolor=red,
 linkcolor=blue,
  urlcolor=magenta,
   breaklinks}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Page styke%
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  left=3cm,
  right=2cm,    
  headheight=17pt, % as per the warning by fancyhdr
  includehead,includefoot,
  heightrounded, % to avoid spurious underfull messages
]{geometry}     

\usepackage{microtype}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}    
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields    
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}    
%\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}    
\fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\bfseries\sffamily\leftmark}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% for the chapter start pages
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%    
  \fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}%    
}    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Cross reference %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{cleveref}    
\crefname{equation}{equation}{equations}    
\Crefname{Equation}{Equation}{Equations}
\crefname{figure}{figura}{figures}
\Crefname{Figure}{Figure}{Figures}
\crefname{section}{section}{sections}    
\Crefname{Section}{Section}{Sections}    
\crefname{table}{table}{tables}    
\Crefname{Table}{Table}{Tables}    
\crefdefaultlabelformat{(#2\textbf{\textup{#1}}#3)}    
\creflabelformat{equation}{(#2\textbf{\textit{\textup{#1}}}#3)}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%others %
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{longtable} % needed for long tables over pages
\usepackage{bigstrut} % needed for the command \bigstrut    
\usepackage{enumerate} % needed for some options in enumerate
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
```

- What are the packages that I should not include, and which packages should I include?
- For the style of the cited reference insides the chapters, I want it as in the below image or in this order `Name, date, reference number in the bibliography`, how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Well you can try commenting out packages and see which ones break the compilation, that should give you an idea of which are needed.  By and large which packages should be included depend on the rest of your document (but please don't post this).  A not unreasonable (but hardly perfect either) rule of thumb would be if commenting out a line doesn't produce a noticeable change and you don't know why the line was there in the first place, it's not necessary!

Comment: @DaiBowen - First, I would not post the whole document!!, second, my question is to point which package isn't used anymore or there is another package have the same function of an existing one with extra features.

Comment: You're loading many packages, and `hyperref` somewhere in between. Put that package right before `cleverref`, `\hypersetup` accordingly too!

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I think you are going the wrong way.

- Do **not** just copy code from the internet **without knowing** what the code or the **package** does.
- Read the documentation of each package you use. If you do **not** understand the documentation, then do **not** use the package ...
- Several packages needs to be called in a **special order**, for example `hyperref` should be called at last, with only two ore three packages, that have to follow `hyperref`. That is explained in the documentation of `hyperref`, try `texdoc hyperref` to read the documentation of `hyperref`.
- Do **not** call packages you do not use in your TeX code.  Unneeded packages can cause conflicts with other packages (remember the needed call order of `hyperref`). *That is the answer of your first question!*
- the style to get the wished layout for the bibliography depends on the used document class, the used bibliography program (BiBTeX or package `biblatex` with Biber).  The documentations describes the standard styles.  Search there for the one you need.  If there is no style you need search for the style near to your needed.  Then we can think how to change that style to what you need. *That is the answer of your second question!*

In your code are several problems, for example what should the following code do?

```
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1256,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ arabic ,english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I guess you want something like:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}
```

but at last that is only a guess.  I suggest you to check each line in your preamble, add an comment after the call to comment for what this package is used.